# Strongly typed collection Implicit and explicit cast

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting

```
public void Foo (IEnumerable<object> objects)
{
}

var strings = new List<string>{"first", "second", "third"};
Foo(strings); // Compilation Error.
Foo(strings.Cast<object>()); // O.k.
```

1. Why the first call to Foo doesn't compile? string derived from object.
2. If I can cast the list to object and it's compiled, why the compiler doesn't do it by his own?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first call compiles in .NET 4.0.

In previous versions, the generic types have to match *exactly*.

I suggest reading the blogs posts of Eric Lippert regarding [variance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/) (covariance and contravariance).

Comment: Why it doesn't compile in .NET < 4.0 ?

Comment: Because it's expecting `IEnumerable<object>` and you're passing it an `IEnumerable<string>` without the covariance information (Introduced to this interface in C#4) it can't know that it's safe to do so.

Comment: @gdoron - Because the compiler has no understanding of variance and covariance and the writer of the compiler didn't put in such inference.

Comment: Note that this will fail to compile in Silverlight 4.0, because even though covariant interfaces are supported, `IEnumerable<T>` is not declared covariant in the Silverlight library.

Answer (score 0):

1. Generics are strict in the sense that you cannot assign a collection of a derived type to a collection of a supertype. You must provide the exact type used to instantiate the collection.
2. Because it cannot know what you want to do. Same reason why the following line does not compile:

   ```
   string s = new object();
   ```

To force an "unsafe" type cast on the user would be too much liberty given to the compiler.

Comment: After covariance is introduced in .NET 4.0, does above statement work in the new framework?

Answer (score 0):

You wan't to look up [co-variance and contra-variance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).

It's new feature in .NET 4.0